# Line Swapping in Vim

Tags: vim, editor, vi

Anyone know of any tricks in vim to easily swap two lines of code? I know that swapping adjacent lines is trivial, but let's say I wanted to swap line 23 with line 52. Is that achievable?

Comment: ESC -> :23 -> dd -> :51 -> p -> k -> dd -> :22 -> p :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

yes!

```
:23m52|51m22
```

then press `Enter`

it is also easy to write a function to do it.

Answer (score 7):

My [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140) has normal and visual mode mappings `]E` and `[E` (and others, similar to the popular *unimpaired* plugin) to swap the current line / selection with `[count]` lines below / above.

I think a `:[range]Swap {range}` command would also be helpful; I'm working on that.

**Edit**: Here it is: [LineJugglerCommands plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4465).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a visual selection when you paste, it will put the selection into the default buffer after pasting. So you would do `23Gdd51GVp23GP`

Comment: You should keep using :23, because it builds even better password. :-P

Comment: That bit about the V-select doing a swap-paste is awesome.  With pop-marks you can avoid the math,  `VY''VP''VP` swaps the current and previous lines, so `23G52GVY''VP''VP`

Comment: ... and a little googling finds the winner, [`:vnoremap <C-X> <ESC>\`.\`\`gvP\`\`P`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines#Visual-mode_swapping), delete some text, v-select what you want to swap with, hit ^X.

Answer (score 2):

user `move` command to move lines. e.g., swap line 23 and line 52:

```
:23m52 | 52m23
```

type `:help move` to get help usage of `move`, it may move a range of lines :-)